# Evolution not seen

Tags: scala, playframework

I have began a Play Scala project and made it have a database by uncommenting in `application.conf`:

```
 default.driver = org.h2.Driver
  default.url = "jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

Then, I created an evolution in `conf/evolutions/default/1.sql`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE task_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE task (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('task_id_seq'),
    label varchar(255)
);

# --- !Downs

DROP TABLE task;
DROP SEQUENCE task_id_seq;
```

So, when I am accessing `localhost:9000` I am expecting to see the message:
`Database default needs evolution!`. However, this does not appear.

I am running in development mode and I don't have the code `evolutionplugin=disabled` anywhere in my project.

Why is the evolution not seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `evolutions` to the list of your library dependencies, as described in the docs https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0/Evolutions.